# I dont understand why i am getting this error CVXPY DCP Problem does not follow DCP rules

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I've been blocked for more than 10 days

I don't understand why I am getting the error and I did everything as the paper suggested and i tried many solution like  Taylor approximation to approximate the non-convex function , here some context to understand

The code and the objective function come from a paper that i'am trying to reproduce one of part of there work to compare there solution with mine the paper tiltle is "Energy Minimization for Wireless Communication
With Rotary-Wing UAV"

the following section present some  abstract to understand the objective :

This code is an implementation of an optimization problem using the CVXPY library. The goal is to find the optimal positions for a set of hovering points, which maximizes the data rate while minimizing the energy consumption of a UAV (Unmanned Aerial Vehicle) that is used to communicate with these points.

The input data is read from a CSV file named 'coordinates.csv' using Pandas. The data is then converted to a NumPy array, and the hovering points are initialized. Several parameters are set, including the maximum distance that the UAV can fly and the maximum number of iterations that the optimization algorithm should perform.

The optimization algorithm used in this code is the Successive Convex Approximation (SCA) algorithm. This algorithm approximates a non-convex optimization problem with a series of convex subproblems that are easier to solve. The algorithm iteratively solves these subproblems until convergence is reached.

In this code, the objective function to be optimized is the sum of two terms: E0*cp.sum(x) and cp.sum((Ph+Pc)dataratenk_arr). The first term represents the energy consumption of the UAV, while the second term represents the data rate. The energy consumption term is minimized, while the data rate term is maximized.

The constraints of the optimization problem are defined in the constraints variable. These constraints ensure that the hovering points do not exceed the maximum distance that the UAV can fly and that the data rate is above a certain threshold.

Here is the code in using cvxpy tool

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from colorama import Fore ,Style
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Read the CSV file as a Pandas DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv('coordinates.csv')

#Here are the content of csv file

'''
array(\[\[  0,   0\],
\[  4, 259\],
\[ 64, 452\],
\[323, 390\],
\[345, 324\],
\[393, 167\],
\[409,  97\],
\[291,  84\],
\[249,  61\],
\[420,  44\]\], dtype=int64)
'''

#Convert the DataFrame to a NumPy array

qk = df.to_numpy()
qk = qk\[1:\]

#Set the hovering points

wk = qk.copy()

#Set the parameters

#UAV power communication consumption in watts

Ph = 168.5
Pc = 5
Pe = 0.1

#Noise power

N0 = 1.6E-10
epsilon = 1e-6 # Convergence threshold
max_dist = 105.57

#Ref  SNR

referenceSnr = 177827.94
alpha = 1

#Data size

datasize= 10
E0 = 36.76

#Initialize gamma

gamma = 30
max_iter = 10

#Initialize the counter

k = 0

#initialization step

qk_new = cp.Variable((9, 2), value=(wk))
qk_tilt = cp.Variable((9,2), nonneg=True)
\#Set the initial hovering location
qk_tilt_l = cp.Variable((9, 2), value=(wk) )
nk = cp.Variable(9, nonneg=True)
x = cp.Variable(8)
index = 0

#Start the SCA algorithm

while index \<1:

    # Define the constraints
    constraints = [cp.sum(x) <= max_dist**2]
    constraints += [cp.sum_squares(qk_tilt[i+1]-qk_tilt[i]) <= x[i] for i in range(8)]
    Rk = [cp.log(1+((referenceSnr)/(100**2+cp.sum_squares(qk_tilt_l[i]-wk[i]))))/cp.log(2) for i in range(9)]
    bk = [((cp.log(cp.exp(1))/cp.log(2)) * referenceSnr * alpha) / (100 ** 2 + cp.sum_squares(qk_tilt_l[i] - wk[i]) * ((100**2 + cp.sum_squares(qk_tilt_l[i] - wk[i])) + referenceSnr)) for i in range(9)]
    term1 = Rk.copy()
    term2 = [bk[i] * (cp.sum_squares(qk_tilt[i]-wk[i])-cp.sum_squares(qk_tilt_l[i]-wk[i])) for i in range(9)]
    constraints += [nk[i] <=(term1[i] - term2[i]) for i in range(9)]
    constraints += [nk[i] >= 0 for i in range(9)]
    nk_arr = cp.vstack([cp.pos(nk[i]) for i in range(9)])
    # Define the objective function
    obj = cp.Minimize(E0*cp.sum(x)+cp.sum((Ph+Pc)*datasize*nk_arr))
    # Define the problem
    prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)
    # Check for convergence
    try:
        # Solve the problem
        prob.solve(verbose=True)
        if cp.sum_squares(qk_tilt_l - qk_tilt) < epsilon**2:
            break
    except Exception as e :
        print("ERROR",e) 
    
    
    # Update variables for next iteration
    qk_tilt_l.value = qk_tilt.value
    l = l + 1 
    index+=1

#Plot the updated points of wk and qk_tilt_l

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(wk\[:, 0\], wk\[:, 1\], label='wk')
plt.scatter(qk_tilt_l.value\[:, 0\], qk_tilt_l.value\[:, 1\], label='qk_tilt_l')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You have some expressions that look like sum_squares of some variables minus another sum_squares of some variables. That is not convex.

Comment: Thanks for replying
the problem was resolved by replacing those constraint with those expression
 Rk = [math.log2(1+(referenceSnr/(100**2+np.sum(np.square(qk_tilt_l[i].value-wk[i]))))) for i in range(10) ]

 bk = [(np.log2(np.exp(1))*referenceSnr*alpha)/( (100**2 +np.sum(np.square(qk_tilt_l[i].value-wk[i]))) * (100**2+(np.sum(np.square(qk_tilt_l[i].value-wk[i]))**alpha) + referenceSnr))  for i in range(10)]

constraints += [nk[i] <=(term1[i] - term2[i]) for i in range(10)]